# Download File Using Curl in php to a specific folder

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

I have a Google Drive File Url suppose for eg.

> https://doc-0c-90-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/rgh255lj001rts71cq6a0d0fmikln8fe/gg1vds4tn8h88pushsj7s1c1qvsb8nk3/1442404800000/16565899266202741945/16565899266202741945/0B86G8IQ4Uf9ATk5wRW9pdXN6OFE?e=download&gd=true

I want to download it to a specific folder for that i am using curl

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
     if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var fileId=doc[google.picker.Document.ID];

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "files/sample.php",
                data: { file_id:fileId,token:oauthToken },
                success: function(data)
                {   

                }
            });
         }
}
```

> sample.php

```
$upload_path='folder_path';
$fileId = $_POST['file_id'];
$oAuthToken = $_POST['token'];

$getUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'. $fileId .'?alt=media';
$authHeader = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $oAuthToken ;

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data($getUrl);
file_put_contents($upload_path.'/'."55dad26bf4165.jpg", $returned_content);
```

this is the name of the file that i am downloading 55dad26bf4165.jpg, but it gives following error :

> string(379)" { "error"; { "errors":[{
>   "domain":"usageLimits","reason":dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
>   message:Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continue use
>   requires signup.".
>   "extendedHelp":"https://code.google.com/apisconsole" }], "code":403,
>   "message":"Daily Limit for  Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued
>   use requires signup."}}"

Please help why this error is occuring.

Comment: Are you using a refresh token to authorize your access? Make sure the token is still valid. Though refresh tokens don't expire, they can still become invalid through other means (limit on tokens or user revocation).

Comment: Andy can u please tell me how can i solve my issue because i'm new to Google Drive and do not know much about its sdk. Can u provide a link for that.